# Access an Array whose name is partially a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, each

Given

```
var wall_list = [];
var granary_list = [];

var building = 'granary';
```

How can I access granary_list using var building, example:

```
$.each('' + building + '_list', function(j, v) { };
```

When I do this it seems it attempts to access `granary_list`, and fails, but if I `console.log('' + building + '_list')` then it logs `granary_list` - not the array, just the word 'granary_list'.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access global variables with window object

```
window[building+'_list'];
```

accesses granary_list variable